# Twitter sharing error in asynchronous call

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I am trying to share tweets on twitter and I am using asynchronous call for that. Here is my code which I am using and I think its quiet generic and simple.

```
 ACAccountType *twitterType = [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    NSDictionary *message = @{@"status": tweetString};
    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"];
    SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest
                              requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                              requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                              URL:requestURL parameters:message];
    NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:twitterType];
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    for (int i = 0; i<[accounts count]; i++) {
        ACAccount *currentAccount = [accounts objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([currentAccount.username isEqualToString:[delegate.twitterAccount username]]) {
            postRequest.account = currentAccount;
            break;
        }
    }

    [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                             NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"URL Response: %@",statusCode);
         if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) {
             [self.delegate twitterPostCompleted:YES];
         } else {
             [self.delegate twitterPostCompleted:NO];
         }
     }];
```

I don't know why but I am unable to even print the `urlResponse`. I have tried to debug this code and it never reaches the line:`NSLog(@"URL Response: %@",statusCode);`

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** `twitterPostCompleted` is a method where I am printing the final output. I am always getting error message which means I am not getting `codeStatus = 200`

Comment: What *is* codeStatus then?

Comment: try this url "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"

Comment: tried this one too but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything was fine in my code except one. I was using

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"];
```

I was suppose to use this one:

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"];
```

Just replaced `http` with `https` and it worked fine.

Comment: hmm great ... :) ... +1 for that identification , above code that i posted works for me ..

Answer (score 1):

First of all u need to ask user permission then only u can proceed like below

```
    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account    accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    // NSDictionary *message = @{@"status": tweetString};//i am using dictionary directly 

    // Request access from the user to access their Twitter account

   [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    {
        if (granted == YES)
        {
          //proceed further 

           NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
            if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
            {
                //use the first account available
                if(selectedIndex == -1) selectedIndex = 0;
                NSLog(@"selected Account at index -> %d",selectedIndex);
                ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]; //hear u can get the selected account in your case from app delegate.

              //Build a twitter request
                 SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:message forKey:@"status"]];

             //set account for post 
                [postRequest setAccount:acct]; 

            //manage the response
                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                 {
                     if(error)
                     {
                         NSLog(@"error");
                         NSLog(@"Twitter response, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         // on successful posting the tweet
                       NSLog(@"Twitter response, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
                     }

                    }];
                 }
            else
            {
              NSLog(@"else part of account less than zero");
            }
        }
        else
        {
           NSLog(@"user does not allowed to access account");
        }

    }]; //completion of block
```

Comment: I am already asking for permissions in other method and then this method is being called. I am getting `statusCode = 403`

Comment: and also one thing u need to consider here, suppose if u reached the update limit then also u can get this error message for more info look at this https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following

Comment: here is the details for all error code hope this helps u https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses